# Install Mathematica 11.0.1 on 64-bit Linux Ubuntu 18.04, an experience

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu

Five times I tried to install Mathematica 11.0.1 on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04
finally successful.

Launching installation from the "Download" folder and three other locations aborted with "$failed".

Only from the **Desktop**   "Mathematica_11.0.1_LINUX.sh"  installed correctly

**My question: Is it just a version 11.0.1 bug, what are the dimensions of this path problem?**

Your experiences?

Useful links

[Wolfram Support: How do I install Mathematica on Linux?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12453)

[Wolfram Support: What are the system requirements for Wolfram products?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/6479)

Comment: For information (my experience is under Debian), I have installed it without problem: in a terminal, in the `~/Downloads` directory, and being root `./Mathematica_11.0.1_LINUX.sh`

Comment: FWIW Mathematica Ubuntu 18.04 was not a supported operating system for Mathematica 11.0.1 in any capacity (they came out 2 years+ apart). It very likely will work, but there are no guarantees.